# windows native copy multple file dialoge

Tags: c#, windows, file, dialog, native

How to copy or move MULTIPLE files and show respective native file dialog ? like this:
[image]

Although I can copy multiple files using this code:

```cs
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
...
FileSystem.CopyFile("1.txt", "2.txt");
FileSystem.CopyFile("3.txt", "4.txt");
...
```

But it shows separately for each of files like:
[image]

I know there's already `FileSystem.CopyDirectory(...)`. But I don't want to copy whole directory. I just want some files from directory to be copied without multiple prompts or separate progress.

I believe its possible. Because I seen that in team viewer and anydesk software.

Comment: How much time do you have? .NET doesn't provide a nice wrapper for it, and you have to hook into the shell's [IFileOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation).  There's a [15yr-old MSDN article on it](https://github.com/mlaily/MSDNMagazine2007-.NET-Matters-IFileOperation-in-Windows-Vista/raw/master/.NET%20Matters%20IFileOperation%20in%20Windows%20Vista.pdf), and a sample implementation in [someone's repo](https://github.com/martin-holy/PictureManager/tree/master/PictureManagerWPF/ShellStuff).

Comment: If .net doesn't have, surely will need to make my own. I was wondering whether someone have done that before already ? IFileOperation looks pretty lowlevel. And that implementation is not native. They made their own dialog.

Comment: Did you read the article, and looked at the code in the repo? Because that code is a really clean implementation of everything you see in the article, doing a native call to what you refer to as "low-level". To be fair, if you want something "native", and .NET hasn't provided it to you in a nice package, your only option is to perform "low-level" calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my earlier comment, we will need to invoke `IFileOperation` through COM - so it's going to be a little dirty with the hooking and marshalling.

For reference, there is an archived MSDN article from 2007 that explains the whole thing step-by-step: ["IFileOperation in Windows Vista" by Steven Toub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2007/december/net-matters-ifileoperation-in-windows-vista).

The author of [PictureManager](https://github.com/martin-holy/PictureManager/tree/39157db54c/PictureManagerWPF/ShellStuff) has nicely wrapped them in a pretty clean implementation. They have kindly licensed the whole project as CC0. This'll save us from having to collect all the Shell P/Invoke code ourselves.

1. Grab the [`ShellStuff` folder](https://github.com/martin-holy/PictureManager/tree/39157db54c/PictureManagerWPF/ShellStuff) from the PictureManager repo.
2. Delete the `FileInformation.cs` and `PicFileOperationProgressSink.cs`.
   They're specific to the app and we won't need them.
3. Edit your `.csproj` file, and add the following:

```xml
<Project ...>
  ...
  <!-- Add this whole ItemGroup: -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <COMReference Include="Shell32">
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
      <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
      <Guid>50a7e9b0-70ef-11d1-b75a-00a0c90564fe</Guid>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <Isolated>false</Isolated>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </COMReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <!-- End add -->
</Project>
```

4. Now use it in your code like so:

```cs
using var fo = new FileOperation();

// There's a whole bunch of flags, all of them well commented.
fo.SetOperationFlags(FileOperationFlags.FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR);

// Define the files you'd like to copy:
fo.CopyItem(@"C:\somewhere\old1.zip", @"C:\elsewhere\", @"new1.zip");
fo.CopyItem(@"C:\somewhere\old2.zip", @"C:\elsewhere\", @"new2.zip");
// ...etc

// Do them all in one go:
fo.PerformOperations();
```

You should see the native dialog performing the copy operations. Including the native confirmation dialog if files with the specified names already exist in the destination.

Comment: Great ! and also pardon me. I used `PictureManager` to copy files and it had implemented its own dialog for moving file. But didn't realise that shellstuff was different and native. Thanks so much :)

Comment: @GrayProgrammerz, my apologies too. I just checked the rest of the PictureManager codebase, and you are correct that they do implement their own copy/move dialog. Only deletion is done through `IFileOperation`. Nonetheless, they have done a really neat job in wrapping up all the complexities behind the native hooks.